# lambdify expressions with native sympy functions

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to lambdify sympy's `exp`, but I run into funny issues when trying to evaluate the function at a `sympy.Symbol`. This

```
import sympy

t = sympy.Symbol('t')
f = sympy.lambdify(t, t**2)
f(t)  # no problem
```

works fine, but this

```
t = sympy.Symbol('t')
f = sympy.lambdify(t, sympy.exp(t))
f(t)
```

gives

```
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

The same goes for all other native sympy functions I've tried (`log`, `sin`, etc.).

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify modules you want to use with `modules` argument of the `lambdify` function:

```
f = sympy.lambdify(t, sympy.exp(t), modules=["sympy"])
```

Answer (score 2):

The main use of `lambdify` is to allow for a fast numerical evaluation of expressions.
This is achieved by replacing abstract and slow SymPy functions (like `sympy.exp`) with faster ones intended for numbers (like `math.exp` or `numpy.exp`).
These cannot handle SymPy symbols (like your `t`) as an argument, which is not what `lambdify` is intended for anyway.

If you call `lambdify` with `dummify=False` as an additional argument, you get a more meaningful error, when calling `f(t)`, namely:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

The expression that cannot be converted here is your argument `t`.

If you want to use a lambdified function with symbols as an argument for some reason, you need to pass `modules=["sympy"]` as an additional argument to `lambdify`.
This argument specifies which module `lambdify` uses to replace SymPy functions (like `sympy.exp`) – in this case, it’s `sympy` again, so nothing actually happens.